# mysql array of objects compare items

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have problem in mysql json that I want to compare one item of object in json array.
example:
in my table i have column aJson that is array :

```
[{"Name":"Mohsen","Code":3},{"Name":"Ali","Code":5},{"Name":"Reza","Code":2}]
```

I want to find the records where Code is greater than 3

output:

```
[{"Name":"Mohsen","Code":3},{"Name":"Ali","Code":5},{"Name":"Reza","Code":8}]
```

same for equal,less,like ...

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be solved using `JSON_EXTRACT` which is available in MySQL version >= 5.7

```
mysql> SELECT mycolumn
     > FROM mytable
     > WHERE mycolumn->"$.Code" > 3
```

`->` is an alias for `JSON_EXTRACT`

Ref:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path

Answer (score -1):

thanks it works as this ...

```
> mysql> SELECT mycolumn
>      > FROM mytable
>      > WHERE mycolumn->"$[*].Code" > 3
```

but what about this sample

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Mohsen",
    "Code": 10,
    "Arrays": [
      {
        "Name": "Mohsen",
        "Code": 6
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ali",
        "Code": 7
      },
      {
        "Name": "Reza",
        "Code": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ali",
    "Code": 11,
    "Arrays": [
      {
        "Name": "Mohsen",
        "Code": 6
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ali",
        "Code": 7
      },
      {
        "Name": "Reza",
        "Code": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Reza",
    "Code": 12,
    "Arrays": [
      {
        "Name": "Mohsen",
        "Code": 6
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ali",
        "Code": 7
      },
      {
        "Name": "Reza",
        "Code": 8
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

find records that Arrays.Code > 3

the follow query did not work ...

```
SELECT * from table WHERE aJson->"$[*].Arrays[*].Code" > 7
```

return all records

Comment: Don't use the *answer* section for asking *questions*. Just upvote and/or accept an answer here and then ask a new question, referencing this thread.